# UPDATE and double INNER JOIN kicking up mysql error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do an `UPDATE` on a double `INNER JOIN`, and getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM pro_users AS u INNER JOIN cAlerts AS c ON c.user_id = u.user_id I' at line 3
```

Here's my mysql code:

```
 UPDATE u 
  SET u.active_member = 0
  FROM pro_users AS u
  INNER JOIN cAlerts AS c
   ON c.user_id = u.user_id
  INNER JOIN srAlerts AS s  
   ON s.user_id = c.user_id
  WHERE c.status=0  
  AND s.active=0 
  AND u.active_member = 1
```

Can you spot my error?

Comment: Use UPDATE pro_users,I think it doesnt know the alias.

Comment: When I use that syntax, I don't use the alias in the set clause.

Comment: I tried using "UPDATE pro_users" instead of "UPDATE u" and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the ISO/ANSI SQL way of doing the update:

```
update pro_users u set active_member = 0
where u.active_member = 1
  and exists ( select *
               from cAlerts c
               where c.user_id = u.user_id
                 and c.status  = 0
             )
  and exists ( select *
               from srAlerts sr
               where sr.user_id = u.user_id
                 and sr.active = 0
             )
```

As far as I know, a `from` clause, with or without joins, in an `update` statement is a Microsoft/Sybase Sql Server aberration.

Edited to note: A little rummaging in the mySql manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html and some SQLFiddling says this will work:

```
update pro_users u
join cAlerts  c  on c.user_id  = u.user_id and c.status  = 0
join srAlerts sr on sr.user_id = u.user_id and sr.active = 0
set active_member = 0
where u.active_member = 1
```

Comment: The ISO/ANSI SQL way was the only syntax that would let me pass, so to speak. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

```
UPDATE 
    pro_users AS u
SET
    u.active_member = 0
WHERE
    u.active_member = 1 
    AND
    (
        SELECT c.user_id
        FROM cAlerts AS c
        WHERE c.user_id = u.user_id AND c.status = 0
        LIMIT 1
    ) IS NOT NULL 
    AND
    (
        SELECT s.user_id
        FROM srAlerts AS s
        WHERE s.user_id = u.user_id AND s.active = 0
        LIMIT 1
    ) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work fine :

```
UPDATE pro_users AS u
INNER JOIN cAlerts AS c
   ON c.user_id = u.user_id AND c.status=0
INNER JOIN srAlerts AS s  
   ON s.user_id = c.user_id AND s.active=0
SET u.active_member = 0
WHERE u.active_member = 1
```